# how to change media query based on if a class exists or not using scss

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have this html element :

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
     <p>Content of the component</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and i'm using this sass mixin:

```
@mixin screen-is($size) {
  $media-query: "";
  $media-query2: "";
  @if $size == tablet {
    $media-query: '(min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px)';
    $media-query2: '(min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1400px)';
  } @else {
    @error 'Unknown size #{$size}';
  }

  @if $media-query2 {
    .parent {
      @media #{$media-query2} {
        @content;
      }
    }
  }

  @media #{$media-query} {
    @content;
  }
}

.content {
  @include screen-is(tablet) {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

My goal is this:

- if class parent exists on DOM, use $media-query2, means apply background-color as lightblue when screen is between 1000px and 1400px.
- if class parent doesnt exist on DOM, use $media-query, means apply background-color as lightblue when screen is between 1000px and 1200px.
  But the problem is that the style is never applied above 1201px, so i think there is something wrong in the usage of media-query2.

Can be tested here: https://codepen.io/abasse/pen/qBgNEYo?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the compiled css code in your codepen, you can see that the generated selector is `.content .parent`, which means, in order for this selector to work `.parent` is supposed to be a child of `.content`.

But as per your goal, what you need is `.parent .content`. So you need to edit the `.content` block in your sass code.

Just move `.content` selector one line down and that should generate the correct css code:

```
@include screen-is(tablet) {
  .content {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```